# python itertools product with steps

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Currently, I have a NumPy array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

And I am doing the product operation in itertools, but I want to add a step function.
For example:

```
[ x for x in itertools.product(*a) ]
```

Result in:

```
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 3, 6), (1, 4, 5), (1, 4, 6), (2, 3, 5), (2, 3, 6), (2, 4, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

For the target output with step (1,1,2):

```
[(1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5)]
```

I can't figure it out, here is the problem.

Comment: The step can also be (1,2,1), (2,1,1), I don't think slice could work with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a list slice:

```
In [578]: import itertools                                                                     
In [579]: a=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]                                                                
In [580]: list(itertools.product(*a))[::2]                                                     
Out[580]: [(1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5)]
```

There may be a `itertools` tools to do this as well.

```
In [586]: list(itertools.islice(itertools.product(*a), None, None,2))                          
Out[586]: [(1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
step = (1,1,2)
[ x for x in itertools.product(*[a[i,::s] for i,s in enumerate(step)])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I think your problem is solve.

import itertools

print(list(itertools.product(*[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]))[::2])